# how i can set current date and time as wallpaper in android pragmatically?

Tags: live-wallpaper

i wants to set current date and time as a wall paper in android problematically.
how it is possible kindly help me , thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Fatemeh but i need help i hope you understand whatever i wrote here.

Comment: You may get better help by clarifying your question.

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Now you can call '**showCurrentTime();**' whenever you want. *Don't forget to update this every second!* :)

```
void showCurrentTime() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c !=null) {
                    c.save();
                    c.drawColor(0xff000000);
                    c.drawText(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).toLocaleString(), mTouchX, mTouchY, mPaint);
                    c.restore();
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
```